# Arrays and Structs

Tags: c, arrays, function, struct

I am taking an online college course introducing C and am completely stumped on my latest project. My professor to research online for the errors but the examples don't seem to match. I started the program on Visual Studio 2013 and now have moved to Code::blocks from the professor's instruction.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <time.h>

typedef struct flightRec { // declare a struct to match the format of the binary data
char FlightNum[7];
char OriginAirportCode[5];
char DestAirportCode[5];
int  timestamp;
} flightRec;

int flightCmp(const void *a, const void *b) // comparison function of DestAirportCode to ascending order
{
    const flightRec *p1 = (flightRec *)a;
    const flightRec *p2 = (flightRec *)b;
    if (p1->DestAirportCode < p2->DestAirportCode)
        return -1;
    else if (p1->DestAirportCode > p2->DestAirportCode)
        return +1;
    else
        return 0;
}

int codeInst(int count, int i, char currCode, char nextCode, flightRec flightInfo[1000]) { // function that counts how many instances of each code exist
    count = 0; // set count to zero
    i = 0;
    currCode = flightInfo[i].DestAirportCode; // get a code from the array, call it currCode
    while (i < 1000 ) { // while you've not come to the end of the array
        nextCode = (&flightInfo[i+1].DestAirportCode); // get the next code from the array
        if (nextCode == currCode) { // if the next code equals the current code
            count += 1; // then add one to count
        }
        else {
            printf("Destination Airport Code: %s Count: %i", flightInfo->DestAirportCode, count); // else output code and count
            currCode = nextCode; // set currCode to nextCode
            count = 0;  // set count to 0
        }
        ++i;
    }


}

int main(){
    flightRec flightInfo[1000];
    int i = 0;
    int codeInst;

    FILE* inFile = NULL;

inFile = fopen("acars.bin", "rb");

struct tm* timestamp;

if (inFile == NULL) {
    printf("Could not open file acars.bin.\n");
    return -1;
}


while (!feof(inFile)) {
    for (i = 0; i < 1000; ++i) {
     fread(&flightInfo[i], sizeof(flightInfo), 1, inFile); // read the acars.bin file into an array of these structs
    }
    for (i = 0; i < 1000; ++i) {
        qsort(flightInfo, 1000, sizeof flightInfo, flightCmp); // sort the array
    }
    for (i = 0; i < 1000; ++i) {
        localtime(flightInfo[i].timestamp); // Do localtime () on the timestamp member of the struct, then asctime on the time struct you get back from localtime
        return timestamp;
    }
    int codeInst(flightInfo); // algorithm to count how many instances of each code exists
    for (i = 0; i < 1000; ++i) {
        printf("Flight Number: %s \nOriginal Airport: %s \nDestination Airport: %s \nDestination Airport Count:%i \nTime: %d \n\n", &flightInfo[i].FlightNum, &flightInfo[i].OriginAirportCode, &flightInfo[i].DestAirportCode, codeInst, timestamp); // print the flightRec structs in form of member columns
    }
    }
fclose(inFile);


    system("pause");
}
```

Build Messages:

```
||=== Build: Debug in Project6 (compiler: GNU GCC Compiler) ===|
In function 'codeInst':|
|28|warning: assignment makes integer from pointer without a cast [enabled by default]|
|30|warning: assignment makes integer from pointer without a cast [enabled by default]|
||In function 'main':|
|70|warning: passing argument 1 of 'localtime' makes pointer from integer without a cast [enabled by default]|
|121|note: expected 'const time_t *' but argument is of type 'int'|
|71|warning: return makes integer from pointer without a cast [enabled by default]|
|74|error: expected declaration specifiers or '...' before 'flightInfo'|
|76|warning: format '%s' expects argument of type 'char *', but argument 2 has type 'char (*)[7]' [-Wformat]|
|76|warning: format '%s' expects argument of type 'char *', but argument 3 has type 'char (*)[5]' [-Wformat]|
|76|warning: format '%s' expects argument of type 'char *', but argument 4 has type 'char (*)[5]' [-Wformat]|
|76|warning: format '%d' expects argument of type 'int', but argument 6 has type 'struct tm *' [-Wformat]|
83|warning: control reaches end of non-void function [-Wreturn-type]|
c||In function 'codeInst':|
|43|warning: control reaches end of non-void function [-Wreturn-type]|
||=== Build failed: 1 error(s), 10 warning(s) (0 minute(s), 0 second(s)) ===|
```

Comment: The first thing that jumps out at me is that "DestAirportCode" is a char array, and yet you're comparing them in flightCmp with <. I assume you need strcmp() here. Likewise, you compare them with == in codeInst.

Comment: `DestAirportCode` is an array with 5 elements (0 to 4), if no element is specified it is handled as a pointer of type `char*` (not `char`), so basically you are trying to store the value of `DestAirportCode` into `currCode`, therefore storing the value of a `char*` into a `char`. Theres your warning, "assignment makes integer from pointer without a cast".

Comment: Your stunt to get `nextCode` makes even less sense. You are trying to store a `char**` (double pointer)  into `char`.

Answer (score 0):

You have initially a function called `codeInst`, after that, in your main function, you declared a integer variable called `codeInst`, in line 73 you coded a statement that I really don't know what you want to do (`int codeInst(flightInfo);`).
I assume that you want to call the function `int codeInst` and for that you must:

- change the name of the variable like `codeInstVarible`
- assign to `codeInstVarible` the function `codeInstVarible = codeInst()`
- and fill all existing parameters in the function in case: `(int count, int i, char currCode, char nextCode, flightRec flightInfo[1000])`

Answer (score 0):

Check out for info:
[c function localtime()][1]

For the error: |121|note: expected 'const time_t *' but argument is of type 'int'|

In your localtime(flightInfo[i].timestamp), 
flightInfo[i].timestamp is an int, not a const time_t *(a pointer to a time_t).

For your int codeInst(flightInfo); function, it should have a return type.

In your main function, you wrote
int codeInst(flightInfo);

Which is incorrect. Look at BarbarianSpock's response.